# PHP - break foreach loop not working

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to break foreach if it is more then 20, but my code dont break the loop. Please fix my code:

```
$limit = 1;
foreach($ids as $id){

    if(check_if_exists($id) == 0){

        echo 'success <br />';

        if ($limit >= 20) break;
        $i++;
    }else{
        echo 'Already exists <br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `$limit++;` instead of `$i++;`. You increasing `$i` not `$limit`

Comment: And whats the value for `$limit`

Comment: Missed this, struggling since past 4 hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$limit = 1;
foreach($ids as $id){

    if(check_if_exists($id) == 0){

        echo 'success <br />';

        if ($limit >= 20) break;

    }else{
        echo 'Already exists <br />';
    }
 $limit++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be

```
if(check_if_exists($id) == 0){

    echo 'success <br />';

    if ($limit >= 20) break;
    $limit++;
}else{
    echo 'Already exists <br />';
}
```

You need to increment `$limit` not `$i`

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment `$limit`.Not `$i`.

```
$limit = 1;
foreach($ids as $id){
    if(check_if_exists($id) == 0){
        echo 'success <br />';
        if ($limit >= 20) 
           break;
        $limit++;
    }else{
        echo 'Already exists <br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing the wrong variable:

```
    if ($limit >= 20) break;
    $limit++;                 // Change this line
}else{
    echo 'Already exists <br />';
```